# Animate hiding the status bar without modifying UINavigationController height

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, statusbar

When you call `UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .Slide)` at any time inside a controller that is embedded in a `UINavigationController` (in a project with view controller based status bar appearance set to `NO`), the status bar will slide away, and the height of the navigation bar will decrease as well. That doesn't work well in my case.

I don't want the navigation bar height to be modified. I want the status bar text to slide away but that's it. I just discovered the Slack app does this exactly when you slide out the left sidebar. The status bar slides up and when you close the sidebar it animates back down without affecting the navigation bar height. How can I obtain that same behavior?

Note that in landscape I do want the default navbar appearance - decreased height and no status bar visible.

Comment: Having the same exact issue. Weird thing is in some parts of my app, the height of the navbar stays the same, but in other places (typically after having pushed a view controller onto my stack), the navbar height shrinks when the bar is temporarily hidden.

Comment: @MasonG.Zhwiti if height of nav bar stays the same, then you probably did not properly call addChildViewController and didMoveToParentViewController methods.